# how to select rows of a dataframe whose value are the same as another dataframe in a certain column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, subset

let say my df1 and df2 are as below:

df1:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,] "n"  "11" "13"
 [2,] "a"  "18" "14"
 [3,] "b"  "13" "10"
```

df2:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "n"  "11" "13"
[2,] "a"  "ll" "kk"
[3,] "b"  "jj" "ii"
```

I want a dubset of df2, such that it contains only those rows of df2 who has same values as df1 in column 1.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "ll" "kk"
[2,] "b"  "jj" "ii"
```

I thought

```
df.2.sub <- df2[df2$CertainColumn == df1$Specific.column]
```

can work. but it does not. would you help me with this please?

Comment: Are those dataframes, or matrices? A [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) helps with knowing your exact data types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

close but need to use the "%in%" operator

```
df.2.sub <- df2[df2$CertainColumn %in% df1$Specific.column,]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a matrix.  Thus, the `$` wouldn't work.  We can use `[` for extracting the first column

```
df2[df2[,1] %in% df1[,1],]
```